# gcloud google app engine wordpress css missing for admin screen

Tags: css, wordpress, google-app-engine, gcloud

I have deployed wordpress on my local host (GAE / Python / PHP) - everything is working fine.

When I deploy the same wordpress application on GAE the Admin screen shows up as text. The CSS files for the admin screens are missing.

here is my app.yaml

```
application: your-project-id [i have changed it to my own project-id]
version: wpfromstarterproject
runtime: php
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /(.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(htm$|html$|css$|js$)
  application_readable: true

- url: /wp-content/(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/wp-content/\1
  upload: wordpress/wp-content/.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$)
  application_readable: true

- url: /(.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$))
  static_files: wordpress/\1
  upload: wordpress/.*\.(ico$|jpg$|png$|gif$)

- url: /wp-admin/(.+)
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/\1
  secure: always

- url: /wp-admin/
  script: wordpress/wp-admin/index.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-login.php
  script: wordpress/wp-login.php
  secure: always

- url: /wp-cron.php
  script: wordpress/wp-cron.php
  login: admin

- url: /xmlrpc.php
  script: wordpress/xmlrpc.php

- url: /wp-(.+).php
  script: wordpress/wp-\1.php

- url: /(.+)?/?
  script: wordpress/index.php
```

Comment: You should see a 404 error in the logs for the missing css.  Have a look at the requested paths and see if they will match with any of the configured static handlers.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. I don't see any 404 errors. I am a new bie here. I looked at "App Engine --> Logs" Google Developers Console. In the timestamp for example I see [GAE ip address ]- - [24/May/2014:08:07:59 -0700] "GET /wp-content/themes/twentyeleven/screenshot.png HTTP/1.1" 200 0 - "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.114 Safari/537.36" "your-project-id" ms=2 cpu_ms=0 app_engine_release=1.9.5 . But the PNG file is not displayed

Comment: Your png appears to have 0 lenght, that's why it isn't showing.  The 0 after the status is the bytes transferred.  e.g. "GET /water_lilies/hardy_water_lilies/pink_laydeker/+img/CRW_7434.jpg?size=CRW_7434.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 106761

Comment: I suggest you look at the "missing" files in the filesystem and check that they are not incomplete, corrupt, etc...  Manually retrieve them via the browser to be sure.